# How could I run Unittest in Superset?

Tags: python, apache-superset

There is a tests folder in [Superset source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset), how could I run them all? I try to use `python xx_test.py` (a py file in the folder) but raised import error

Comment: What text in your error? Maybe you don't specify directory? `python {your path}\xx_test.py`, example: `python c:\python\xx_test.py`

Comment: I use `python tests/core_tests.py` and then error occured as follows:```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/core_tests.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .base_tests import SupersetTestCase
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-packag``` I think that's because I run a wrong py file and then caused some import error